# Losing data in an array with WCF

Tags: arrays, wcf, entity-framework-4

I've got the following sample of code on my WCF I'll get the data from the database with EF 4.0:

```
public IEnumerable<Row> GetRowsUrenBriefje(int urenBriefjeId)
{
    UrenregistratieEntities ue = new UrenregistratieEntities();
    IEnumerable<Row> rows = (from row in ue.Rows
                             where row.RegistrationId == urenBriefjeId
                             select row);
    return rows;
}
```

At the client side i got the following code:

```
IEnumerable<UrenregistratieService.Row> rows = svc.GetRowsUrenBriefje(registration.IdRegistration, true);
foreach (UrenregistratieService.Row row in rows)
{
    UrenRij.Add(new UrenRij(row));
}
```

When i debug an look at the rows value before it return is contains multiple values. On the client side i als got also multiple values in the array but they aren't except for the first value. this issue is also showing up in another webmethod.

I hope someone can help me out, if  need to clearify myself just ask and i will try.

Comment: Why are you sending a bool value `true` when you call your method?

Comment: that's if the registrationId is specified

Comment: I guess my point was that you're calling a method that's not the same as the one you posted (with only one param). The implementation could be entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has to do with the fact that you're returning a raw IEnumerable. Can you try calling .ToList on the LINQ EF query before returning from the server side and see if that predictably returns all the data you expect? Let me know if it does I can go into more detail about what might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest changing your web service's method signature to return either an array or List. Something like this:

- `public List<Row> GetRowsUrenBriefje()`
- `public Row[] GetRowsUrenBriefje()`

Implement like this:

```
public List<Row> GetRowsUrenBriefje(int urenBriefjeId)
{
    UrenregistratieEntities ue = new UrenregistratieEntities();
    return ue.Rows.Where(r=> r.RegistrationId == urenBriefjeId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: tried that also, i tackled this problem by casting the entities from to custom classes and passing these throug the webservice.